# How to replace current value in row with next (or previous value in same column of dataframe)?

Tags: r

Apologies in advance if this has been asked before but all I can find is how to replace NA's; never matching the configuration I am facing here. In this case, I would simply like to replace 0s with the next row's value. An example with how to map the previous row would also help (although I assume it should be fairly close to mapping the next row).

Below is a piece of code that works but it runs very slowly when applied to a large  dataframe. I was thinking there has to be a better solution maybe using lapply(). Note that unlike the example given here, the real dataframe has nothing to be "grouped by" so dplyr may not be an option. Thank you again

```
iris$ind <- seq_along(iris$Sepal.Length)
iris$ind <- ifelse(iris$ind %% 2 == 0, 0, iris$ind)

for(i in seq_along(iris$ind)){

  ifelse(iris$ind[i] == 0, 
         iris$ind[i] <- iris$ind[i + 1], iris$ind )  

}
```

Comment: What is the exact logic regarding what happens if the next row also be zero?

Comment: Apologies for not specifying. There will never be two consecutive 0s in the “ind” column

Comment: `library(tidyverse); iris %>% mutate(ind = na_if(ind, 0)) %>% fill(ind, .direction = "up")`

Comment: Wait: Are you trying to find `NA` values, or zero values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try using `lead` from the `dplyr` package:

```
iris$ind <- ifelse(iris$ind == 0,
                   lead(iris$ind, order_by=iris$Sepal.Length),
                   iris$ind)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to use `fill` from `dplyr`, but it only works with filling `NA` values with previous or next values. So, why don't you replace the `0` values with `NA` values and then use `fill`. You may use `mutate` in `dplyr` to do that, like this:

```
iris <- iris %>% mutate(ind = ifelse(ind == 0, NA, ind)) %>% fill(ind)
```

The default `.direction` of `fill` is `"down"`, which means replacing a `0` with its previous value. To replace a `0` with its next value, you need to change the `.direction` to `"up"`, like this:

```
iris <- iris %>% mutate(ind = ifelse(ind == 0, NA, ind)) %>% fill(ind, .direction="up")
```

Hope it helps.